# Nginx cannot find ~/public_html/info.php

Tags: php, nginx

I am new to PHP and want to learn it. So I install Nginx, PHP, MariaDB in my computer:

1. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64-bit.
2. Nginx (don't know how to check version)
3. PHP 7.2
4. The default www is /var/www/html. It works fine for HTML and PHP file. (info.php only contain phpinfo();)
5. A normal user with directory ~/public_html/index.html and info.php. index.html could shown (Hello world), but info.php (same as above) got 404.

/etc/nginx/site-available/default

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /var/www/html;

index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
    alias /home/$1/public_html$2;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    autoindex on;
}
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have PHP files in two roots, so you need two `location` blocks to process those URIs. The simplest solution is to use a nested `location` block.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
location ~ ^/~(?<user>[^/]+)(?<path>/.*)?$ {
    alias /home/$1/public_html$2;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    autoindex on;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
    }
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
}
```

Place the outer `location ~ \.php$` block below, otherwise it will match all PHP URIs first. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Use named captures, as numeric captures will be out of scope in the nested `location` block.

I don't know what's in your snippets file, but you probably want to avoid `try_files` (because of [this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) with `alias`) and you need to use `$request_filename` to locate the path to the `SCRIPT_FILENAME`.

The `if` block is added to avoid [passing uncontrolled requests](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php) to PHP. See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Surely that `if` could be replaced with `try_files $url =404` or something similar?

Comment: I don’t use try_files with alias. But it might work and there are strange workarounds. See the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me (inspired by [previous answer](https://superuser.com/a/1403161/1654472) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/SurajDadral/22e66533d006f11859b49f8d6445093c)):

```
        location ~ ^/~(?<user>.+?)(?<path>/.*)?$ {
                alias /home/$user/public_html$path;
                autoindex on;
                index index.php index.html index.htm;

                location ~ \.php$ {
                        alias /home/$user/public_html;

                        # default fastcgi settings
                        include fastcgi_params;

                        # A bit of added security -- not full proof, but can help
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

                        # Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
                        if (!-f $document_root/$path) {return 404;}

                        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$path;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;

                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                }
        }
```

What changed comparing to previous answer to correctly find the script on the filesystem:

- `$request_filename` => `$document_root/$path`
- alias command

Hope that will help anyone ending up here like I did!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).